# Convergent sequences and functions on them

Tags: general-topology

Let $X$ and $Y$ be two Hausdorff spaces, and $f,g : X \to Y$ be two continuous functions. Let $S$ be a convergent sequence, say $S=(x_1,x_2,x_3,\ldots)$ with $x_k \in X$ for all $k \ge 1$, with limit $\ell \in X$.

Assume that $f(x_k) = g(x_k)$ for all $k \ge 1$. Clearly, since $f$ and $g$ are continuous, we know that $f(x_k) \to f(\ell)$ and $g(x_k) \to g(\ell)$ as  $k \to \infty$. I have *two questions*:

- Does it follow that $f(\ell) = g(\ell)$? (My gut feeling is "*yes*", but how does one prove this?)
- What can be said about $f|_U$ and $g|_U$, where $U$ is an open neighbourhood with $\ell \in U \subseteq X$?

**EDIT** I've added the condition that both $X$ and $Y$ be Hausdorff.

Comment: For your first question, what do you know about sequences? Regarding your second question, the same can be said about the restrictions, provided you remove the initial terms of the sequence that may not belong to $U$.

Comment: It would be practically impossible for me to write down everything I know about sequences. I've studied differential geometry up to and beyond postgraduate level, so I guess quite a lot. Should I also write everything I know about topology?

Comment: No offense intended, sorry. The uniqueness of a limit (in $\mathbb{R}$ first, then in metric spaces, and finally in Hausdorff spaces) is pretty much the first thing we see when we are introduced to sequences. Since you know a whole lot of mathematics, it is simply strange that you ask this question.

Comment: @julien I'm becoming an old man these days. It's 10 years since I last studied analysis and topology seriously. I've focused on other things since then, and the known facts slip from one's mind.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answer to updated version:

Yes, and the assumption that $X$ is Hausdorff isn't needed.  As you mentioned, the sequence $(f(x_k))=(g(x_k))$ in $Y$ converges to $f(\ell)$ and to $g(\ell)$.  Because $Y$ is Hausdorff, limits of sequences are unique, so this implies that $f(\ell)=g(\ell)$.

I do not know what is being asked about $f|_U$ and $g|_U$, but for example, they need not be equal on any such neighborhood.  Perhaps the example $X=Y=\mathbb R$, $f=0$, $g(x)=x\sin(1/x)$, $g(0)=0$, $x_n=\dfrac{1}{\pi n}$ would be relevant?  (Or $f=0$, $g(x)=\max\{-x,0\}$, $x_n=1/n$.)

For holomorphic functions on connected open subsets of $\mathbb C$, or real analytic functions on intervals in $\mathbb R$, we would have $f=g$ if $x_n\neq \ell$ for all $n$.

**Added**: To see that limits in Hausdorff spaces are unique, suppose that $(a_n)$ is a sequence in a Hausdorff space $Y$ converging to $a\in Y$ and let $b\neq a$ be another element of $Y$.  It will be shown that $(a_n)$ does not converge to $b$.

Let $U$ and $V$ be open neighborhoods of $a$ and $b$ respectively such that $U\cap V=\varnothing$.  Because $(a_n)\to a$, eventually $a_n\in U$.  This implies that eventually $a_n\not\in V$, and therefore $(a_n)\not\to b$.

---

Answer to original version:

If $Y$ is Hausdorff, then limits of sequences in $Y$ are unique when they exist, so yes.

Without this assumption there are counterexamples.  For example, if $Y=\{0,1\}$ with indiscrete topology, $X=Y$, $S=(0,0,0,\ldots)$, $\ell=1$, $f(0)=f(1)=0$, $g(0)=0$, $g(1)=1$.  ($X$ could be any space that has a sequence $(x_n)$ converging to a limit $\ell$ such that $x_n\neq \ell$ for all $n$, so e.g. $X=\mathbb R$ would also work, but I took $X=Y$ for economy.)

Comment: So $Y$ being Hausdorff is a sufficient condition for $f(\ell)=g(\ell)$, but is it necessary? What are your thoughts about the second question?

Comment: @FlybyNight: There will be certain circumstances in which $Y$ is not Hausdorff and yet $f(\ell)$ is forced to equal $g(\ell)$.  Hausdorff can be characterized in terms of *every* convergent *net* having a unique limit.  It is not enough to work with sequences.  As to whether there are useful necessary and sufficient conditions, I am at a loss.  I do not have significant thoughts on the second question; I don't know what is being asked.

Comment: I've changed the question to say that $X$ and $Y$ are both Hausdorff. In terms of the second questions, I suppose that I have metric spaces in mind, or holomorphic functions. Basically, some nice, geometrical category. (I know I didn't say that, but your replies have made me think about it.) What would I need, for example, for $f|_U \equiv g|_U$?

Comment: @FlybyNight: I just updated before seeing your comment.  If the functions are holomorphic on a connected open subset of $\mathbb C$, or real analytic on an interval in $\mathbb R$, then a sufficient condition to get $f=g$ would be that $\ell\neq x_n$ for all $n$, i.e. that $\ell$ is a limit point of the set $\{x_n\}$.

Comment: So if $f$ and $g$ agree on a convergent sequence then they agree in a connected open subset of $\mathbb{C}$? How would one determine the largest" possible set? Moreover, as I mentioned: "*How could one prove this?*" (A link would be fine!)

Comment: @FlybyNight: If they are both holomorphic and if the limit of the convergent sequence also lies in the same open set (not on the boundary), then yes.  Finding larger domains to which this function can be extended is in the theory of analytic continuation: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analytic_continuation.  That article summarizes things better than I can.

Comment: "How could one prove this?" You mean that limits of sequences in Hausdorff spaces are unique?  Or the [identity theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_theorem) for holomorphic functions?

Comment: It's okay, I misread your post. I know about analytic continuation, and I'm familiar with the statement and proof of the identity theorem. Thanks for the comments.